# Is it possible to use Beyond Compare to identify columns that exist in one Excel sheet but not another?

Tags: excel, beyondcompare

I have two Excel sheets and one sheet has more columns than the other sheet and I need to identify those columns that are not present in both sheets.

I've tried using Beyond Compare tool but cannot figure out how to identify columns not present in both sheets.

Comment: You can try their own forum: https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remark in advance: I use beyond compare 4 Pro Edition.
I'm not sure if each function is available in the non-pro version.

If I compare

[image]

and

[image]

Then I get:
[image]

You can see the red little square on the first different column.

You could add now a dummy columns at this place (Excel)
Then you get:
[image]

The columns with different columns are again marked red.

In  Session->Session Settings you can check the column mapping:
[image]

With the right mouse click you can move the columns:
[image]

The result:
[image]

---

Another possibility (without data comparison):

> I need to identify those columns that are not present in both sheets.

1. Open a new text compare in beyond compare.
2. Go to your first excel and mark the header line, Copy the line (Ctrl-C)
3. Paste the line in Beyond compare
4. Go to your second excel and mark the header line, Copy the line (Ctrl-C)
5. Paste the line in Beyond compare
6. check the result:\[image]

Comment: Thank you, Knut, your second recommendation was the easiest and most obvious! Worked perfectly.